# How to import JsonParser and Gson in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to use the `JsonParser` interface and `Gson` but when I type them in the code Android Studio doesn't recognize them and so I can't even import them automatically.

Can someone explain me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add the jar to libs folder.
- Right click on the jar and select "Add as
  library"
- Make sure your applications build.gradle has the newly added
  jar listed in compile files

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)